# MongoDB and composite primary keys

Tags: mongodb, composite-primary-key, primary-key-design

I'm trying to determine the best way to deal with a composite primary key in a mongo db. The main key for interacting with the data in this system is made up of 2 uuids. The combination of uuids is guaranteed to be unique, but neither of the individual uuids is.

I see a couple of ways of managing this:

1. Use an object for the primary key that is made up of 2 values (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7225657/13181))
2. Use a standard auto-generated mongo object id as the primary key, store my key in two separate fields, and then create a composite index on those two fields
3. Make the primary key a hash of the 2 uuids
4. Some other awesome solution that I currently am unaware of

What are the performance implications of these approaches?

For option 1, I'm worried about the insert performance due to having non sequential keys. I know this can kill traditional RDBMS systems and I've seen indications that this could be true in MongoDB as well.

For option 2, it seems a little odd to have a primary key that would never be used by the system. Also, it seems that query performance might not be as good as in option 1. In a traditional RDBMS a clustered index gives the best query results. How relevant is this in MongoDB?

For option 3, this would create one single id field, but again it wouldn't be sequential when inserting. Are there any other pros/cons to this approach?

For option 4, well... what is option 4?

Also, there's some discussion of possibly using CouchDB instead of MongoDB at some point in the future. Would using CouchDB suggest a different solution?

**MORE INFO:** some background about the problem can be found [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/236309/strategy-for-generating-unique-and-secure-identifiers-for-use-in-a-sometimes-of)

Comment: probably the most important question is how are you going to be accessing this data?  writing obviously inserts - updates? what about queries?  deletes ever?

Comment: Mostly writes. Then updates (mostly in large bursts). A fair number of inserts (again, mostly in big bursts). Occasional deletes.

Comment: what field(s) will the updates be using?  one or both of the uuids?

Comment: Updates, deletes and queries will be against both fields

Comment: together or individually?  Or some of each?  I.e. is each update going to be targeted to a single unique document (hence providing both uuid values)?

Comment: That's correct, each update will target a specific document (no multi document updates)

Comment: @herbrandson Hi, can you show me how you have implemented the composite primary key? What I am doing right now is `StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner("/");
   joiner.add(info.getUserID()).add(idOfApp);
   String idName = joiner.toString();`, and it is working fine but using composite key is what I think is a far better approach and I tried it by using BasciDBObject and appending the two values of my field, but that did not work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. So if you can show me the full implementation then that will be of great help. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You should go with option 1.

The main reason is that you say you are worried about performance - using the _id index which is always there and already unique will allow you to save having to maintain a second unique index.

> For option 1, I'm worried about the insert performance do to having
>   non sequential keys. I know this can kill traditional RDBMS systems
>   and I've seen indications that this could be true in MongoDB as well.

Your other options do not avoid this problem, they just shift it from the _id index to the secondary unique index - but now you have two indexes, once that's right-balanced and the other one that's random access.

There is only one reason to question option 1 and that is if you plan to access the documents by just one or just the other UUID value.  As long as you are always providing both values and (this part is very important) you always order them the same way in all your queries, then the _id index will be efficiently serving its full purpose.

As an elaboration on why you have to make sure you always order the two UUID values the same way, when comparing subdocuments `{ a:1, b:2 }` is not equal to `{ b:2, a:1 }` - you could have a collection where two documents had those values for _id.   So if you store _id with field a first, then you must always keep that order in all of your documents and queries.

The other caution is that index on `_id:1` will be usable for query:

```
db.collection.find({_id:{a:1,b:2}})
```

but it will *not* be usable for query

```
db.collection.find({"_id.a":1, "_id.b":2})
```

Comment: Okay and thanks, I'll keep that in mind. I actually figured it out by myself. `BasicDBObject compositeKey = new BasicDBObject("deviceId", deviceID).append("id", id);      
   String newID = compositeKey.toJson();` where deviceID and id contains the value that I need to append. Thanks once again.

Comment: As for the second caution you mentioned, do you think that if we go with the first option (create a composite ID from the two values), should we replicate the two values as well? Thus we would have the performance benefits of using the composite ID and also able to query the values.

Comment: Guys are you sure the dot notation is not working? For me it does. Using MongoDB v4.2.6

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4z1jgch0lhnqebq/Screenshot%202020-04-27%2023.03.58.png?dl=0

Comment: Oh the queries will work they just won’t be able to use _id index.

Comment: One thing to note is that option 1 will be hard to change in the future if something about the primary key changes. It will be a lot easier to drop and add a new index than it will be to rewrite all your data with a different "_id".

Comment: This is the best solution for "big data". Other answers seem to assume indexes are "free".  They take up quite a bit of space.

Answer (score 11):

I have an option 4 for you:

Use the automatic `_id` field and add 2 single field indexes for both uuid's instead of a single composite index.

1. The `_id` index would be sequential (although that's less important in `MongoDB`), easily shardable, and you can let `MongoDB` manage it.
2. The 2 uuid indexes let you to make any kind of query you need (with the first one, with the second or with both in any order) and they take up less space than 1 compound index.
3. In case you use both indexes (and other ones as well) in the same query `MongoDB` will [intersect them](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-intersection/) (new in v2.6) as if you were using a compound index.

Comment: Sharding a sequential index is a bad idea, it will not be evenly shared accross all shards + you will have useless index space filled up because you have 2 index instead of 1 (big deal on large collections).

Comment: @JonathanMuller Not if you shard them using a hash. "Hashed keys work well with fields that increase monotonically like ObjectId" https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/#sharding-hashed-sharding

Answer (score 9):

I'd go for the 2 option and there is why

1. Having two separate fields instead of the one concatenated from both uuids as suggested in 1st, will leave you the flexibility to create other combinations of indexes to support the future query requests or if turns out, that the cardinality of one key is higher then another.
2. having non sequential keys could help you to avoid the hotspots while inserting in sharded environment, so its not such a bad option. Sharding is the best way, for my opinion, to scale inserts and updates on the collections, since the write locking is on database level (prior to 2.6) or collection level (2.6 version)

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful! Just to clarify, you say that having non-sequential keys could help w/ sharded environments. However, option #2 is the one that _would_ give you sequential ids. Am I not understanding something?

Comment: You right, the non sequential keys comment is related to the statement in your question, where you said, that sequential keys are helpful in RDBMS

Comment: In most RDBMS, records are physically stored on disk ordered by their primary key. When doing a non sequential insert, all the records have to be physically moved. This is what makes inserts slow w/ a non sequential id. It's also why queries against the clustered key are so fast. (You likely already knew that, but I just wanted to put my question in context). 

Are you saying that this is not the case in MongoDB? My reading had led me to believe that was still a consideration. I know that the standard MongoDB ObjectIDs are sequential. I assumed that was part of the reason.

Comment: Clustered index in RDBMS implies that the data is kept in the same order as index. Which requires additional work to insert the data in "between". In mongo, there is no such a thing as clustered index and data is not required to be added to the disk at the same order as the _id index

Comment: Ah, that's what I was missing. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 5):

I would've gone with option 2. You can still make an index that handles both the UUID fields, and performance should be the same as a compound primary key, except it'll be much easier to work with.

Also, in my experience, I've never regretted giving something a unique ID, even if it wasn't strictly required. Perhaps that's an unpopular opinion though.