# MongoDB: comparison of subdocuments

Tags: mongodb

In a Mongo collection where the natural primary key would be given by two fields, let's say `a` and `b`, I was thinking of using the `_id` field as a subdocument containing the two fields.

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23164417/mongodb-and-composite-primary-keys#), this is certainly a good solution if the queries always filter on both fields (and, unless I misunderstand, filter **one** specific value for both fields).

In my case they don't: I need to be able to filter separately by both fields.
However, I can write stuff like this:

```
... .find({_id : { $eq: {a : 1} } })
```

which performs an object comparison, but even this:

```
... .find({_id : { $lt: {a : 1} } })
```

So my questions are:

- what is the definition of the sorting of objects in MongoDB? I couldn't find anything in the documentation
- assuming it is something reasonable like: compare all fields in their order, if the first `n` are equal and the `(n+1)`th are not, return the ordering of the `(n+1)`th; is this stable enough to actually use, or could it change in the future?

I would like to (reliably) use the index, instead of making a new one, at least the first of the two fields.

Comment: Why does sorting matter here? Would you not be able to specify a sort condition like `.sort({ "_id.a": 1, "_id.b": 1 })` or something similar? I would certainly not recommend relying on the current (undocumented) sort order for fields that are of type object.

Comment: I'm talking about the sorting according to which the $lt and $gt operators work.
I agree I wouldn't rely on an undocumented feature. I was only hoping someone had more luck than me reading the docs