# Querying composite primary key in mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have a mongodb collection in which document is stored in the below format

```
{
    "_id": {
        "host_ip": "192.41.15.161",
        "date": "2020-02-02T08:18:09.207Z"
    },
    "path": "/apache_pb.gif",
    "request": "GET /apache_pb.gif HTTP/1.0",
    "status": 200
}
```

where "host_ip" and "date" should be composite primary key i.e. (unique together) and there exists an _id index, which I think is created based on these two fields

So, how can I query based on host_ip and date together so that the "_id" index can be utilized?

Tried using
`db.collection.find({_id: {host_ip: "192.41.15.161", date: {$gte: ISODate('2020-02-02T08:00:00:00.000Z')}}})`, but it does not work, it does not even return the record which should match. Is it not the correct way to query?

Query like 
`db.collection.find({"_id.host_ip": "192.41.15.161", "_id.date": {$gte: ISODate('2020-02-02T08:00:00:00.000Z')}})`, worked but it does not use the index created on "_id"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When querying for an `_id` composite primary key, mongo seems to only look for exact matches (essentially treating `_id` like a string), so when you query for `_id: {a: x, $gte: y}` it looks for `"{a: x, $gte: y}"` and doesn't allow querying by any portion of the object.

```
> db.test.insert({_id: {a: 1, b: 2}});
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.test.find({_id: {a: 1}}); // no results
> db.test.find({_id: {a: 1, b: {$eq: 2}}}); // no results
```

As far as solving your problem goes, I'd probably set up a new unique compound index on the fields you care about & ignore the `_id` field entirely.

[MongoDB and composite primary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23164417/mongodb-and-composite-primary-keys) has a few more details.

Comment: Thanks, I think then taking option 2 in given link (selected answer) would be a better option for me as _id index will be large because of it being composite field, as is of no use. While creating a compound index on two seperate fields (host_ip and date) would be a better option