# Mongojack- how to create composite Primary key

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java, mongo-jackson-mapper, mongojack

We are using mongodb & MongoJack for mapping our collections.
  There is a need where we need to create composite primary key.
 We are not getting correct configuration how to use @Id annotation.

Can anyone help in this or should we avoid using mapper for the same?

[MongoDB Composite Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222062/mongodb-composite-key) link tells what we want to do . But we want this through mongojack..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below syntax should work. Note replacing String class with your Key class

```
private static JacksonDBCollection<Test, TestKey> coll = MongoDB.getCollection("test", Test.class, TestKey.class);
```