# Id on more than one properties: EF Equivalent in MongoDb

Tags: c#, mongodb, entity-framework, primary-key, schemaless

In Entity Framework we can define a Primary Key on more  than one columns.

something like this

```
public class MyEntity
{
    [Key, Column(Order=0)]
    public int MyFirstKeyProperty { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order=1)]
    public int MySecondKeyProperty { get; set; }          
}
```

Is there any way to achieve such behavior in mongoDb ?

Answer (score -1):

you can create CompoundIndex on the database. below link has elaborated on it.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/

in C# you can create this way

```
           grades.Indexes.CreateMany(Builders<MyCollection>.IndexKeys.Ascending(x => x.Name))

            //if you don't have mycollection, and your collection is of type IMongoCollection<BSonDocument> then you can use this

            grades.Indexes.CreateManyAsync("{ Name: 1 }","{ID:-1}");
```

Comment: what I  have asked for is primary key not indexes  ?!!

Comment: you just have to add attribute {unique:true}. this will enforce unique constraint   https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/

Comment: and here why for example you need a primary key not a unique key "In sharded clusters, if you do not use the _id field as the shard key, then your application must ensure the uniqueness of the values in the _id field to prevent errors. This is most-often done by using a standard auto-generated ObjectId".

Comment: Thank you. thats helpful

Comment: may be this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222062/mongodb-composite-key/7225657#7225657