# Symfony, ODM: how to set multiply ids annotation

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-odm

So the question is how to provide two or more identifiers keys? I couldn't find any answers on this question in google search... Here is example:

```
class Customer
{
    /**
     * @ODM\Id
     *
     * @JMS\Expose
     * @JMS\Type("string")
     *
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ODM\Id(strategy="INCREMENT")
     *
     * @JMS\Expose
     * @JMS\Type("integer")
     *
     */
    protected $customerId;
```

So in this case I have second id which increment as I wrote, but first id became null. If I remove and write just `* @ODM\Field(type="integer")` everything is ok, but no increment of `customerId`. So how can I have to ids in document? Or I'm wrong and I don't do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identifier is automatically mapped as `_id` field therefore there can be only 1 field mapped as `@Id`.

Done similar things in the past and I'd suggest keeping `\MongoId` as document identifier and generating incremented `customerId` in your code instead of relying on ODM to do so. Making such generator is pretty straightforward, you need to hook into persisting document (be it in your domain code, which I advice, or leveraging `prePersist` event) and write generator similar to ODM's [IncrementGenerator](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/a250f14f899931fcb21ee0af6d2e490f589b2051/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Id/IncrementGenerator.php#L53).

Answer (score 0):

You can only have two key one of string the other integer as part of a composite key, as per this documentation:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html

So try:

```
class Customer
{
    /**
     * @ODM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="string")
     *
     * @JMS\Expose
     * @JMS\Type("string")
     *
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ODM\Id(strategy="INCREMENT")
     * @ORM\Column(name="customerId", type="integer")
     *
     * @JMS\Expose
     * @JMS\Type("integer")
     *
     */
    protected $customerId;
```

I think that should work for you.

Comment: Be attentive! I do not use ODM, so the ORM notation have no sense, and solutions for ORM cant implement to ODM notation. I use only ODM, only mongodb.

Comment: Sorry, your post had the example with `ORM` so I was mistaken. I did a search online and I believe Doctrine with ODM does not support composite Ids. However, I found this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222062/mongodb-composite-key/7225657#7225657  which might be helpful for you. I can remove my answer if you think it's unsuitable and post what's in that link as an answer.