# ODM MongoDB autoincrement doesn't work

Tags: php, mongodb, zend-framework, doctrine-odm, zend-framework3

I am, trying to increment the field, and get no results;
Here is my code:

```
class Query
{
    /**
     * @ODM\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ODM\Field(type="int", strategy="increment")
     *
     */
    protected $my_id = 0;

    public function incrementMyId()
    {
        $this->my_id++;
    }
}
```

When in action i try:

```
$query = new Query(); 
$query->incrementMyId(); 
$this->documentManager->persist($query);
$this->documentManager->flush();
```

The field **my_id** is always equals to **int(1);**
Can u help me with this issue? Thanks.

I use ZF3,

> "alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter": "^1. 
>   "doctrine/doctrine-mongo-odm-module": "^0.11.    
>   "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "^1.1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strategy `increment` for a normal field means that the query updating document in the database will use `$inc` operator instead of `$set`, exactly as [per documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/storage-strategies.html#increment).

You seem to want to have both auto-generated `ObjectId` identifier and unique auto-incremented one for the entire collection. For such usage please see my [other answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42317991/5982920)